# Multiple Language Support Not Working in TextMesh Pro

Tags: text, fonts, unity-game-engine

I am currently using TextMesh Pro. While Input other languages in input field, its shows white boxes. Its work fine while typing English alphabet and use other languages font in input field.

Here's the screen shot of the following error..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au8O7.png)

Here typing "hello" in English working fine in "Chinese" but if a input Chinese alphabet, it shows white boxes.

I also tries to make font asset as unicode, but its still not working. I am currently using unity 5.6.2

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, this is the process I went by, to solve it for me:

1. I found [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-russian-letters-arent-shown-instead-of-them-blocks-help-please.468481/) very helpful, 


2. [Digital Native Studios Font Asset Creator](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/font/) was where I made my mind how to do it


3. head to Google Fonts, I chose Cyrillic in language selection section and downloaded the zip file, and extracted all in this folder: "\Assets\TextMesh Pro\Fonts"


4. I got to Window menu from menu bar of unity, then to TextMeshPro there, and from the next cascading menu I clicked "Font Asset Creator"


5. There it was straightforward thanks to its Author, I simply chose my font, then from "Character set" I chose "Unicode Range (Hex)", also, before that I googled "unicode hex range Cyrillic", and I knew that it's "[0400-04FF](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF)" range and finally clicked "Generate Font Atlas" there


6. After saving I got back to unity, in Canvas I selected my TextMeshPro Text component, from Font Asset I found and selected the SDF file that was generated (easy to find by name), and also from "Material Preset" bellow that I selected the related (same name) material. I typed text in Cyrillic and magically everything worked! 

I hope this helps and will be happy to help further in what I can.

**Edit**

[This youtube clip maybe helpful too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEnz6UAtLdw)

Answer (score 0):

### Step 01: Download Font

open the link https://fonts.google.com/ . Click right on corner Browse fonts click. and type the  font in search box.
Font List

1. Noto Sans [find On Google fonts]
2. Roboto [find On Google fonts] 3)
3. Code2000 [But it's not open source.]
4. Futura
5. Arial
   Download Family for your favorite font.

### Step 02:   Install TextMeshPro plugin

from Package manager. After copy the font file NotoSans-Regular.ttf and paste to this directory. [Ex. Asset > TextMesh Pro > Resources > Fonts & Materials  > paste NotoSans-Regular.ttf file]

### Step 03: Create SDF for font. if any one

1. **Select  NotoSans-Regular.ttf file** and create font asset SDF from menu bar Assets > Create > TextMeshPro > Font Asset  OR
2. Short Cut-> Shift + Ctrl + F12 OR
3. **Select  NotoSans-Regular.ttf file** and click mouse right button and create SDF from Create > TextMeshPro > Font Asset
   [image]

### Step 04: Add Other font SDF in to your primary or existing font SDF.

Select primary font SDF and show the inspector go to Fallback Font Assets. Added the NotoSans-Regular SDF in to Fallback list. [Multiple fonts added in to primary font SDF]
[image]